# ton>Hover over an <a> tag to change a button color inside the <a> tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

My webpage is constructed as:

```
   <a class="hoverMe" href="">   
      <div class="somediv1">
         <div class="somediv2">
           <div class="somediv3">
              <button class="changeColor"></button>
           </div>
          </div>   
      </div>
   </a> 


   <a class="hoverMe" href="">   
      <div class="somediv1">
         <div class="somediv2">
           <div class="somediv3">
              <button class="changeColor"></button>
           </div>
          </div>   
      </div>
   </a>
```

I want to be able to change the color of the button inside the particular `<a>  </a>` that's being hovered over. How should I write the javascript to do it? Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: why not simply use the CSS `:hover` pseudo selector?

Comment: Having a `<button>` inside `<a>` is not valid HTML

Comment: Why do you even have a button inside an a tag? I suppose this will cause even further problems down the road.

Comment: Just use an anchor tag and make it look in CSS like it is a button...

Comment: No javascript, `a:hover button` does the trick. In your case, `somediv1:hover button` also does the trick. But not sure what you want to do with this invalid dom sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First at all, you only need a button to fire an JS onclick event. In every other case you use a div to style a "button". Also a button is not an empty tag and therefor needs a closing tag `<button>Text</button>`

Just like this:

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

a div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: min-content;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<a href=""><div>I'm a Link-Button</div></a>
```

to change the color during hover, you dont need JS. You can simply use the `:hover` pseudo selector like this:

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

a div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: min-content;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 5px;
}

a:hover div {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href=""><div>I'm a Link-Button</div></a>
```

As you insist on using your invalid HTML and seem not to understand the use of :hover the same for your code:

```css
.hoverMe:hover .changeColor {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<a class="hoverMe" href="">
  <div class="somediv1">
    <div class="somediv2">
      <div class="somediv3">
        <button class="changeColor">Button 1</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>


<a class="hoverMe" href="">
  <div class="somediv1">
    <div class="somediv2">
      <div class="somediv3">
        <button class="changeColor">Button 2</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the button tag problem! Unfortunately this did not answer my original question of how to hover an a tag to change the button which resides inside nested divs, and the divs are placed inside the a tag :(

Comment: like we already wrote: use `:hover` read the comments `a:hover button { background-color: red; }` but again, this is very basic HTML and CSS which could be easily found with little to no research efford. it doesnt matter how much stuff you got nested, always works the same.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty basic question checking docs usually can help you. Check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp) out

The use of `:hover` pseudo selector will help you achieve what you want. In our example we see the `a:hover` action which enables the hover color change.

```css
a:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}

a {
  font: bold 11px Arial;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  color: #333333;
  padding: 2px 6px 2px 6px;
  border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-right: 1px solid #333333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
  border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}
```

```html
 <a href="https://www.w3schools.com">w3schools.com</a>
     <a href="https://www.wikipedia.org">wikipedia.org</a>
    
     <p><b>Note:</b> The :hover selector style links on mouse-over.</p>
```

Comment: hm, this is great but did not answer my question.  The button has to be inside nested div and inside an a tag, I need to hover over the a tag to change the button color ,not the other way around.